# I Want to change the Value of a cell only if all the rest of cells in the same column are not empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I Want to change the Value of a cell only if all the rest of cells in the same column are not empty.
eg: Column A
A1 is frozen as header with value "Y" (A1="Y")
I want to check all the cells in column "A" from A2:A100 not to be empty. Only when all the cells in the range are filled/have content/is not empty, I want to change the Value of A1 to "Z" (A1="Z") otherwise the value of A1 will remain "Y" (A1="Y").

Can anyone help? tried different functions but not getting it work the way it needs to.

Thanks
Regards
AG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the cells are filled manually put this in A1:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A2:A100)=ROWS(A2:A100),"Z","Y")
```

If the cells are filled with formula that may return an empty string, `""` Then use:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A100<>""))=ROWS(A2:A100),"Z","Y")
```

Comment: AWESOME !! thank you very much. I tries something like this, but didn't work for some reason. this works perfect. Cheers